# HDTV with HEVC (h.265 / x.265) support?

Tags: usb, video, television, hdtv

I'm looking for a HDTV capable of playing [HEVC h.265](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X265) encoded videos from USB/PEN drive. Most of the HDTVs support h.264 standard but I could find any playing h.265 standard.

More over it would be better if it has the below features (not necessarily but better if they are present)

1. Multiple USB ports
2. Multiple HDMI ports
3. LED display
4. Ethernet / Wifi support
5. 4K resolution class
6. 32 inches or higher
7. 3D

My price range is at most $1800 and it should not be an Android TV.

Comment: You want to look at LG's webOS capable TVs. They seem to be able to play HEVC files.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 55' Samsung Q6FN. It's a QLED TV. It has everything you listed except for 3D.

The current model is the Q70R. It costs around 1.2k USD.

Check out the RTINGS review for this TV.
https://www.rtings.com/tv/reviews/samsung/q70-q70r-qled